# React Native : Set state properly

Tags: react-native, state

Hi Guys i would like to know how I can set my state in function of my click on a toggle.

I mean the first time the user will click on the checkbox, I'll call my toggle function and I want to set my state to true and if the user click again on the checkbox I would like to set my state to false.

Might be something like this.setState({ isStore: true ? false }) ?

This is my code:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
  loaded: true,
  email: '',
  password: '',
  storeName: '',
  ceoName: '',
  address: '',
  city: '',
  category: '',
  isStore: false
 };
}

<CheckBox
  label='Run a business?'
  onChange={()=>this.toggleStatus()}
/>

toggleStatus(){
  this.setState({
   status:!this.state.status,
   isStore: true
 });
}
```

thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Where is status in this.state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer with

```
toggleStatus(){
  this.setState({
   status:!this.state.status, // <- where is status in your constructor?!
   isStore: true
 });
}
```

to

> Might be something like this.setState({ isStore: true ? false }) ?

a simple

```
toggleStatus(){
  this.setState({
   isStore: !this.state.isStore
 });
}
```

should do it. I am not sure what you try to accomplish with you `status` there...

Comment: Thank you very much Stophface.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to update to this.

```
toggleStatus(){
  this.setState({isStore: !this.state.isStore});
}
```